# Listing all resources in a namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to see all resources in a namespace.

Doing `kubectl get all` will, despite of the name, not list things like services and ingresses.

If I know the the type I can explicitly ask for that particular type, but it seems there is also no command for listing all possible types. (Especially `kubectl get` does for example not list custom types).

How to show all resources before for example deleting that namespace?

Comment: Its really a shame there doesn't seem to be a way to do this via `kubectl`.

Comment: I created an issue for this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/109408

Comment: There are reasons why this won't be done. See: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/28955

Comment: As of kubectl version : `v1.28.0`, `kubectl get all --namespace={your_namespace}` also returns services.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151#issuecomment-402003022) , the supported way to list all resources is to iterate through all the api versions listed by `kubectl api-resources`:

> kubectl api-resources enumerates the resource types available in your cluster.
>
> this means you can combine it with kubectl get to actually list every instance of every resource type in a namespace:

```
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
  | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -l <label>=<value> -n <namespace>
```

Comment: It would be nice to have an updated answer, which could exclude forbidden GVK .

Comment: just added `alias k8s-show-ns=" kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name  | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found  -n"` as an alias to my rc file. thanks

Comment: My slightly different take on it:

`function kgetall {
   kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | xargs -n1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found "$@"
}`. Adding `complete -F __start_kubectl kgetall` will get you completion on this as well.

Comment: what worked for me ```kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
  | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -nl -n <namespace>```

Comment: It can be useful to find out what resource name was that is listed in the namespace use the `-t` option in xargs. `xargs -t -n 1 ..`
This is xargs debugging and will show the command that it is executing. 
Which api resource it was trying to list.

Answer (score 82):

This may not get *all* resources but it may be what someone is looking for

```
kubectl get all,cm,secret,ing -A
```

This seems to get most of the resources, prefixed with the type.

At least, it gets:

- pod
- service
- daemonset
- deployment
- replicaset
- statefulset
- job
- configmap
- secret
- ingress

This doesn't get custom resources but does get services.

Else this does something similar:

```
for i in `kubectl api-resources | awk '{print $1}'`; do kubectl get $i; done
```

Running v1.13

Answer (score 37):

I ended up needing this same functionality due to failed Helm deployments that left remnants in a specific namespace. Here's a function you can put in your bash profile:

```sh
function kubectlgetall {
  for i in $(kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | grep -v "events.events.k8s.io" | grep -v "events" | sort | uniq); do
    echo "Resource:" $i
    
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        kubectl get --ignore-not-found ${i}
    else
        kubectl -n ${1} get --ignore-not-found ${i}
    fi
  done
}
```

Usage: `kubectlgetall <namespace>`

Example: get all resources from the `kafka` namespace:

`kubectlgetall kafka`

Comment: Thank you for this. It would be nice if this functionality were added to kubctl rather than needing to do this kind of workaround, but this definitely solves my problems.

Comment: It doesn't need to be added "to kubectl" see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubectl/kubectl-plugins/

Answer (score 12):

Complete solution

```
kubectl -n <NAMESPACE> get $(kubectl api-resources --namespaced=true --no-headers -o name | egrep -v 'events|nodes' | paste -s -d, - ) --no-headers
```

Answer (score 10):

[Answer of rcorre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016918/8356225) is correct but for N resources it make N requests to cluster (so for a lot of resources this approach is very slow). Moreover, *not found resources* (that have not instances) are very slow for getting with `kubectl get`.

There is a better way to make a request for multiple resources:

```sh
kubectl get pods,svc,secrets
```

instead of

```sh
kubectl get pods
kubectl get svc
kubectl get secrets
```

---

So the answer is:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# get all names and concatenate them with comma
NAMES="$(kubectl api-resources \
                 --namespaced \
                 --verbs list \
                 -o name \
           | tr '\n' ,)"

# ${NAMES:0:-1} -- because of `tr` command added trailing comma
# --show-kind is optional
kubectl get "${NAMES:0:-1}" --show-kind
```

or

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# get all names
NAMES=( $(kubectl api-resources \
                  --namespaced \
                  --verbs list \
                  -o name) )

# Now join names into single string delimited with comma
# Note *, not @
IFS=,
NAMES="${NAMES[*]}"
unset IFS

# --show-kind is enabled implicitly
kubectl get "$NAMES"
```

Comment: In fact, the same number of API requests will be made in both cases, you can check it if add `--v 6` parameter to `kubectl` command:

```kubectl get pods,svc,secrets --v 6```

When you call `kubectl` commands separately it causes config loading every time. In the combined command, the configuration will be requested once. Config loading takes about 10-12ms.

Comment: You are right: the same number of API requests. The difference is that in case of `pods,svc,secrets` there are three requests within one HTTP/2 connection. But when you make call for each resource separately, you establish new HTTP/2 connection for each of them.

Comment: I don't know why yet, but some resources like `issuers.certmanager.k8s.io` or `leases.coordination.k8s.io` requires more time to get than another (4 seconds vs 200ms for ordinar like `pods`). 
Whey I get them separately, time add up. When I get then at-once (`pods,svc,...`), time of call stay the same.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [kubectl krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/plugins/) plug-in, I will suggest using [get-all](https://github.com/corneliusweig/ketall).

It can get almost 90% of resources. Including `configmap`, `secret`, `endpoints`, `istio`, etc...

Comment: Great tip - it has options to include/exclude, as well as \

Answer (score 7):

A Powershell implementation of [rcorre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016918/1515123) would look like

```
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | `
%{ kubectl get $_ --show-kind --ignore-not-found -l <label>=<value> -n <namespace> }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a 100% solution, but for me works the following

```
kgetall='kubectl get namespace,replicaset,secret,nodes,job,daemonset,statefulset,ingress,configmap,pv,pvc,service,deployment,pod --all-namespaces'
```

and just call

```
kgetall
```

But obviously I expected that behavior from

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

in the first place.

Comment: If you want results from single namespace only then change --all-namespaces to -n <NAMESPACE>

Answer (score 2):

All kubernetes objects are stored in etcd.

All objects are stored in ETCD v3 the following way:

```
/registry/<object_type>/<namespace>/<name>
```

I suggest just to take the list of all resources of some namespace from etcd v3 directly:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=<etcd_ip>:2379 get / --prefix --keys-only | grep -E "^/\w+/\w+/<namespace>/+"
```

Comment: This is useful if you have a self-managed Kubernetes cluster - it won't be possible with GKE, EKS and other managed services.

Answer (score 2):

Just covering some basics:

- Resources can be fetched using the `kubectl get` command.
- Resources can be filtered by namespace using the `-n [NAMESPACE]` or `--namespace [NAMESPACE]` flags.

  - I will use the `-A` (same as `--all-namespaces`) flag in the following examples for brevity.

Some of the other answers show how to list available resource types:

```sh
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list -o name
```

With this in mind, we can get all resources, leveraging [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html) and [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```sh
kubectl get "all,$(kubectl api-resources --verbs=list -o name | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g')" -A
```

An alternative to `xargs` is to use [`tr`](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html):

```sh
kubectl get "$(kubectl api-resources --verbs=list -o name | tr '\n' ',')all" -A
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be se simplest way to print out all the resource name in a kubernetes cluster:

```
#!/bin/bash

for resource in [$(kubectl api-resources -o name | tr "\n" " ")]
do 
  kubectl get $resource --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}'
done
```

to specify the namespace you just need to modify the line in the loop setting --namespace=<your-namespace> and remove --all-namespaces

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PowerShell version of what other's have said

```
function getall {
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691479/listing-all-resources-in-a-namespace
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        $namespace
    )
    $types=kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name
    kubectl get $($types -join ",") -n $namespace --show-kind
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58588040/5930295), in fish shell it looks like below.

Add the following function to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```sh
function kall
  kubectl -n $argv get (string join ',' (kubectl api-resources --namespaced --verbs list -o name))
end
```