# List all objects from a given namespace using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to list all objects that are present in a specific namespace in kubernetes.

```
kubectl get all -n <namespace>
```

the above command doesn't list all available objects from the given namespace. Is there a way to list them using kubectl?

i can list all objects that i want by passing them to kubectl. but i dont want that.

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get deployment,rs,sts,ds,job,cronjobs -oyaml
```

Comment: Hi, This is convention not to shoot yourself in the foot, https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-cli/kubectl-conventions.md#rules-for-extending-special-resource-alias---all

Comment: Here is the hacks people are using . 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691479/listing-all-resources-in-a-namespace

Comment: @P Ekambaram, does the answer satisfy your questions ?

Comment: no. not completely

Answer (score 4):

First of all these following rules decide if the resource will be part of the **all** Category or not.

> Here are the rules to add a new resource to the  [kubectl get all](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-cli/kubectl-conventions.md#rules-for-extending-special-resource-alias---all) output.

- No cluster scoped resources
- No namespace admin level resources (limits, quota, policy,
  authorization rules)
- No resources that are potentially unrecoverable (secrets and pvc)
- Resources that are considered "similar" to #3 should be grouped the
  same (configmaps)

To **Answer your question** This is taken from [rcorre's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691479/listing-all-resources-in-a-namespace)

```
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
  | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -l <label>=<value> -n <namespace>
```

Lastly, If you want to add a Custom Resource in **all category**, you need to provide these field in your CRD spec. [custom-resource-definitions:categories](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#categories)

```
# categories is a list of grouped resources the custom resource belongs to.
    categories:
    - all
```

Answer (score 1):

For listing all the objects in your namespace:

```
kubectl get all -n=<namespace>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this:

```sh
kubectl get `kubectl api-resources -o name | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//'`
```

Source : [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
kubectl -n your_namespace get all
```

Comment: This doesn't list all the resources of what the OP is looking for