# Regarding Google Kubernetes Cluster backup

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, backup, google-kubernetes-engine

I am looking to understand things regarding Google Kubernetes Cluster backup . I came across this document but this seems to be more on GCP Anthos On premises GKE Cluster .

https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/archive/1.1/how-to/administration/backing-up

I saw few blogs talking of a GKE feature to create a clone of existing GKE Cluster but I cannot find any option in GCP Console to create new cluster by cloning an existing GKE Cluster.

https://blog.doit-intl.com/google-kubernetes-engine-cluster-migration-with-velero-4a140b018f32

Can somebody please confirm if this cloning feature is still available in GKE or it is deprecated ?

Apart from Cloning a GKE Cluster , we need to take backup of Cluster resources and PersistentVolumes.
It seems Veloro is a useful tool for this and it is GKE aware.

https://velero.io/

I am looking for further suggestions regarding GKE Cluster backup which takes care of both Cluster resources and persistent volumes. Any recommendation/best practises from Google on GKE backup

Comment: double-post: https://serverfault.com/questions/1035790/understanding-gke-backup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I saw few blogs talking of a GKE feature to create a clone of existing GKE Cluster but I cannot find any option in GCP Console to create new cluster by cloning an existing GKE Cluster.

> Can somebody please confirm if this cloning feature is still available in GKE or it is deprecated ?

You can in fact create a **duplicate!** By going into:

- `Cloud Console` (Web UI) -> `Kubernetes Engine` -> `CLUSTER-NAME` -> `Duplicate`.

[image: DUPLICATE]

> **Disclaimer!**
>
> This option will create a duplicate of your cluster but it **will not** copy the workload (`Pods`, `Deployments`, `Services`, `Persistent Volumes`, etc.)

---

Transferring your workload will heavily depend on the resources that you are using. You will need to carefully consider all of the resources and choose the solution most appropriate to your use case.

Solution mentioned in the question:

- *[Velero.io](https://velero.io/)*

Storage specific:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Persistent Volumes: Volume snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots)* - available from `GKE` version `1.17`
- Make snapshots/images from existing `PV's` and create new `PV's` from this snapshots/images:

  - *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Disks: Restore and delete snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots#console)*
  - *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Persistent Volumes: Preexisting PD](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd)*

---

It could be beneficiary to add that you could also take a different approach and use tools that are designed to provision resources multiple times. Once created "scripts" could be used multiple times (on multiple clusters when migrating etc.). Examples of such tools:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager)*
- *[Terraform.io](https://www.terraform.io/)*
- *[Ansible.com](https://www.ansible.com/)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Youtube.com: How to Backup and Restore Your Kubernetes Cluster - Annette Clewett & Dylan Murray, Red Hat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyzgS-KKuoo)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Storage overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/storage-overview)*

Comment: Thanks. That's a great answer. Any suggestion for taking backup of Kubernetes resources like Pod/Service/Egress definition , ConfigMap etc

Comment: @ZamaQues You should be able to create a backup of those resources using `Velero`. You could also generate `YAML` definitions with `kubectl get RESOURCE_TYPE RESOURCE_NAME -o yaml`

Comment: Thanks. I tried velero successfully. Instead of generating yaml for each resource , can we take backup of entire namespace using some native kubernetes command using one shot?

Comment: Have you checked this thread by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691479/listing-all-resources-in-a-namespace/53016918