# Delete all resource in kubernetes with helm go sdk

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I am using widely the helm go sdk. Now i do not know always which resources are still in the cluster and would have a call to completely clean it.

I can get the KubeClient, but found only the [delete method expecting the resources](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v3.5.4/pkg/kube/client.go).

Maybe the programmatical call to `kubectl delete all --all`? Best would be including the namespace resource itself.

Or do I need to request the names of all resources and then delete it?

Thank you!

Comment: easiest way would be using kubectl command

Comment: Take care. Kubectl get all don’t retrieve all ressources. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016918/2858926

Comment: Deleting all resources from a Kubernetes cluster, will just break the cluster, you'd be better deleting and re-creating the cluster entirely. If you're creating user resources and want to clean those up, I'd recommend ensuring that all resources are created in a single namespace and then if you can't track the resources, just delete the namespace.

Comment: Also if you're using cluster level resources where that won't work, you could add a label to every resource you create and delete all resources with that label.

Comment: I solved it not very satisfying by doing a "helm list" and then delete the ressources. As soon a ressource is installed manuelly over kubectl it won't work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already mentioned in the comments, the way to list all the resources would be by using a proper `kubectl` command. The idea behind it is well explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151#issuecomment-402003022):

> `kubectl api-resources` enumerates the resource types available in
> your cluster.
>
> this means you can combine it with `kubectl get` to actually list every
> instance of every resource type in a namespace:
>
> ```
> kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
>   | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -l <label>=<value> -n <namespace>
> ```

With that you will be able to request names of all the resources and than delete them.