# How to find list of permissions that I have in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, permissions

I am able to `list`, `get` pods, secrets, deployments and many other resources. I have cluster wide access for many resources. Is there some way to see the consolidated list of all permissions that I have in a kubernetes cluster?

The result of `kubectl auth can-i '*' '*'` is `no` though.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Lemme know if that works out for you. Good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get a consolidated list of all permissions that you have in a k8s cluster.

Looking at the `help` & `examples` for the `kubectl auth can-i` command it needs a `VERB` which is a logical Kubernetes API verb like `'get'`, `'list'`, `'watch'`, `'delete'`, etc. and a `TYPE` which is a Kubernetes resource.

The result of `kubectl auth can-i '*' '*'` is understandably `no` as it checks if you can do everything in your current namespace - which evidently is not true in your case and thus the `no` response.

You will need to run `kubectl auth can-i` for each resource and each action that you want to check (of course you would be able to use `-A` or `--all-namespaces` flag for all namespaces) but I would imagine you can write a script to run a loop on this command for all/some resources to check permissions for all/some actions.

**Update:**

If you'd really want to, you could run a script to loop through certain `kubectl` cmds to achieve this.

The script would (could) look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for namespace in $(kubectl get namespaces | awk '{ print $1 }' | tail -n +2); do
  echo "Current namespace: $namespace"
  for resource in $(kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name); do
    for action in get list watch create update patch delete; do
      echo "- $action $resource"
      kubectl auth can-i "$action" "$resource" --namespace="$namespace"
    done
  done
done
```

Note: There could be variations of how you do this in `bash`.

I'll explain a bit:

- Firstly, we're fetching all the namespaces, printing only the 1st column, and `-n +2` basically means “start passing through on the second line of output”.
- Next, we're fetching most (if not all) resource types available in your cluster. Picked up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016918/1722326).
- Iterating through a few common actions supported in K8s. Found most (if not all) on [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/) page.
- And then just run `kubectl auth can-i` cmd on each resource, action, and namespace we got in the earlier commands.

While it works, it takes a lot of time as we have a lot of namespaces and you'd have to go through a lot of output to find something or you would end up redirecting the output to a file and searching for fields.

Realistically, you would wanna run it only on a few namespaces at a time to check on a few actions on a few resources.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for namespace in default calico-system; do
  echo "Current namespace: $namespace"
  for resource in pods deployments.apps; do
    for action in get create; do
      echo "- $action $resource"
      kubectl auth can-i "$action" "$resource" --namespace="$namespace"
    done
  done
done
```

It is a lot faster and would help you easily find what you're looking for.

Sample output:

```
Current namespace: default
- get pods
yes
- create pods
no
- get deployments.apps
yes
- create deployments.apps
no
Current namespace: calico-system
- get pods
yes
- create pods
no
- get deployments.apps
yes
- create deployments.apps
no
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this works, will tweak the formatting to best suit me someday. Happy weekend

Answer (score 1):

you can try with the command : `kubectl auth can-i --list` or `kubectl auth can-i --list --as=[user-name]`

You can also check this [documentation](https://www.mankier.com/1/kubectl-auth-can-i)

Comment: Doesn't that list permissions for the current namespace only?

Comment: You could also add the option, -A, --all-namespaces

Comment: You can't. `list` option can't be specified with neither `quiet`, `all-namespaces` nor `subresource` options